# Thread-safe in Singleton pattern which holder members

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, happens-before

I have this sample code with Singleton pattern:

```
class Singleton{
    private static Singleton instance;
  private int count;
  private Singleton(){}
  public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(){
    if(instance==null){
        instance=new Singleton();
    }
    return instance;
  }
  public int getCount(){return count;}
  public void setCount(int count){this.count=count;}
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    Thread t1=new Thread(()->{
        while(Singleton.getInstance().getCount()==0){
        //loop
      }
      System.out.println("exist t1 with count="+Singleton.getInstance().getCount());
    });
    t1.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000); //time out to force t1 start before t2
    Thread t2=new Thread(()->{
        Singleton.getInstance().setCount(10000);
    });
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  }
}
```

I have a question: Method `getCount` and `setCount` which called in two thread t1, t2 is thread-safe, isn't it?

Comment: "Method `getCount` and `setCount` which called in two thread t1, t2 is thread-safe, isn't it?" - No, they are NOT thread safe, and a **singleton** is completely **unrelated** in that respect. Assume both threads have completed their calls to `Singleton.getInstance()` which returns the same instance, and only after that both threads call `getCount` and `setCount` *concurrently*. These methods access the same *non-volatile* variable `<instance>.count` without syncrhonization and one of these accesses - from `setCount` - is a *write* access. By definition, this is a **data race**.

Comment: I think this is a correct answer. If the reference to an object instance was visible to other threads (ex. using volatile), members of that object couldn't be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

> Method getCount/setCount which called in two thread t1, t2 is thread-safe, isn't it?

If you intention is to make the changes made by t2 *visible* to t1 - yes, the count set by thread 2 will be visible to thread t1.

This is because thread 1 gets the singleton instance every time by calling `getInstance` which is a `synchronized` method. This establishes a *happens-before* relationship and the changes made by thread 2 will be visible to thread 1.

---

However, if you change your code to call `getInstance` only once and use that that reference to call `getCount`, then the changes made by another thread (t2) may not become visible to thread t1 and it can keep looping.

```
 Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();
    while(s.getCount()==0){
        //loop
    }
```

To make the changes get reflected, you have to make `count` a *volatile*

```
private volatile int count;
```

Comment: In happens-before relationship, all changes are visible to thread `t2` after a synchronized unlock will be visible to thread `t1`. However, when thread `t2` call `Main.getInstance()`, all changes before this method calling will be visible to thread `t1`, but `setCount` is called after a synchronized unlock, so, `count` can invisible to thread `t1`.

Comment: t1 enters a `synchronized` block each time it calls `getInstance`.

Comment: But `t1` only see the changes made by `t2` before `t2` unlock sychronized following Java Memory Model rules.

Comment: There is nothing like *unlock sychronized*. Unable to get your point